# JasperReports MongoDB Query How to access subdocument?

Tags: mongodb, jasper-reports, mongodb-query

We have a document stored in `MongoDB` which looks like this:

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "demo-name",
    "lastModified" : ISODate("2015-01-07T07:19:35Z"),
    "snapshot" : {
        "rows" : [
            {
                "quantity" : 100,
                "rate" : 32,
                "description" : "22MM SHROUDED PBA RED",
                "productCatlgNo" : "3MA40 00 AA0"
            },
            {
                "quantity" : 125,
                "rate" : 32,
                "description" : "22MM SHROUDED PBA BLACK",
                "productCatlgNo" : "3MA40 01 AA0"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to access this document and read only the data stored in the `snapshot.rows` in `JasperStudio` report designer using the following query:

```
{
    'collectionName' : 'views.abcdefghi',
    'findQuery' : {
        'name': 'demo-name'
    },
    'findFields':{
        'snapshot.rows': 1
    }
}
```

But the output contains only `snapshot.rows` whereas I want the inner details of the documents present in the `rows`.

How should I go about it?

Comment: dont know about jasper, but you can use this code in mongo shell: db.collection.aggregate([
{$project : {"rows" : "$snapshot.rows"}}
])

Comment: Thank you for the lead @Disposer 

[This link](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jaspersoft-mongodb-query-language) Talks about `$project` but I can't figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This could be your answer (based on this [link](https://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/mongodb-aggregation-queries-basics-mongolab))

```
}
   runCommand: 
   {
      aggregate : 'views.abcdefghi',
      pipeline : 
               [ 
                   {$match : {"name" : "demo-name"}},
                   {$project : {"rows" : "$snapshot.rows" }},
               ]
   }
}
```

after running the command (on sample document) `db.test.aggregate([ {$project : {"rows" : "$snapshot.rows"}} ]).result` in mongo shell I had this result (just ids and rows):

```
{
    "0" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("54b9017ec283f0c25c9cbf5e"),
        "rows" : [ 
            {
                "quantity" : 100,
                "rate" : 32,
                "description" : "22MM SHROUDED PBA RED",
                "productCatlgNo" : "3MA40 00 AA0"
            }, 
            {
                "quantity" : 125,
                "rate" : 32,
                "description" : "22MM SHROUDED PBA BLACK",
                "productCatlgNo" : "3MA40 01 AA0"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: `{
    'collectionName' : 'views.abcdefghi',
    'findQuery' : {
        '_id': 'saleswise-abc-analysis'
    },
 'findFields':{
  'snapshot.items': 1
 },
 runCommand:{
  aggregate : 'views.abcdefghi',
  pipeline : [ {$project : {"items" : "$snapshot.items"}} ]

 }
}`

Gives me only the _id as a part of my output.

Comment: I updated the answer with the output, I have no problem

Comment: Ok I found why I don't get the desired output, when I run your command on my db. I get results from all where there exists a `$snapshot.rows` I need to select only the one where `name: demo-name`